# renaming the online tag to online-algorithms

Tags: discussion, tags

If you browse the [online](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) tag, you will see that most questions are about [online algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) but a few are about online (as in internet) resources, such as:

[Statistics for online dating sites](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18451/4872)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12303/4872

[Is there a site to post my survey to so I can get a sample representative of the population?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5462/4872)

[Intro to statistics for an MD?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/223/4872)

I am assuming that those are not suppose to have the online tag. To avoid future confusion, I propose to rename the online tag to online-algorithms (or something of the sort) and of course, to remove the online tag from the above 4 questions.

Comment: I removed the online tag on the above 4 questions, but do not have sufficient rep and need my edits approved.

Comment: Done.  I created a new "Internet" tag and applied it to two of those questions.

Answer (score 1):

Good catch!

Because the majority of uses are of the algorithmic nature, it might be better to reserve the original [online](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) for that meaning and disambiguate the other with something like [online-internet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-internet) or just [internet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet).  We will also need to complete the tag wikis for both so that people learn to use them as intended.

Comment: the only problem might be that people will continue to misuse the online tag to tag internet-resources questions in the future. I guess we could write a tag wiki, but it is not obvious that people read those. If we replace online by online-algorithm then no such confusion would arise.